# Python GLPK - Appdata write - Permission denied

Tags: python, glpk, pyomo

I am running an optimization problem in python using pyomo 4.3.11388 and the GLPK solver 4.57 on Windows 7.
While running 8 calls in parallel with multiprocessing.Pool GLPK has a rare write problem to the \Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp folder:
This happens only once out of more than thousands of successful runs.
Anyone can help? Thanks!

ERROR: "[base]\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", 575, solve
    Solver log:
    GLPSOL: GLPK LP/MIP Solver, v4.57
    Parameter(s) specified in the command line:
     --write C:\Users\JGOREN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4fo_8eqx.glpk.raw --wglp
     C:\Users\JGOREN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmps7viej_q.glpk.glp --cpxlp C:\Users\JGOREN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjnqvqljx.pyomo.lp
    Reading problem data from 'C:\Users\JGOREN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjnqvqljx.pyomo.lp'...
    25 rows, 45 columns, 69 non-zeros
    223 lines were read
    Writing problem data to 'C:\Users\JGOREN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmps7viej_q.glpk.glp'...
    Unable to create 'C:\Users\JGOREN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmps7viej_q.glpk.glp' - Permission denied
    Unable to write problem in GLPK format

Comment: I had similar issue with CBC solver. Sometimes I get a write permission error. I wonder if it is trying to write somewhere else (like use disk for paging) and the system is denying it such access